# Override mongomapper has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns, mongomapper

I use Rails 3 with MongoMapper.
I want to add some records to the result of `has many` association.

For example, `user has_many posts`

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document

  many :posts
end
```

By default it will show only posts which belongs to the user, but if he/she specify special option in query (or in the user's settings menu, say `show-commented=true`), then I also need to add posts where user left any comments. So I think to override `posts` method

```
def posts
  super + (show_commented_posts ? commented_posts : [])
end
```

But of course it doesn't work. How can I correctly override this method using mongo_mapper? Or is there any better approach for that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding methods on mongomapper is a very bad idea, you should try to refrain from doing it as it creates a lot of problems that are hard to trace back (I've been burned before by this).

Instead, you should consider using a scope such as

```
class Post
  scope :related_to_user, lambda {|user| where('$or' => [ {user_id: user.id}, {'comments.user_id' => user.id}]) }
end
```

Then you can call

```
Post.related_to_user(current_user)
```